# Lighthouse give Browser errors with Google Ads script

Tags: google-adsense

I to test my Website with Lighthouse, the report to say,

> Browser errors were logged to the console 
>    js/adsbygoogle.js(pagead2.googlesyndication.com) Description N

How I understand my Problem is from my Google Ads script inside on **div**, how to have it,

```
<div class="siebte">
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- tablet2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
  style="display:inline-block;width:480px;height:90px"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-123"
  data-ad-slot="456"></ins>
<script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

</div>
```

As a solution I to ready [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677825), but I don't know how to implement it...

Can Please someone help me and with easy words explain how to solve these Problem.. very Thanks!